# Copying the meta data from one org to another of a managed package application

Tags: apex, managed-package, custom-object

I have installed one managed package (free) in my org and now I want to build the similar apps with more enhancements in **different org** However most things are restricted as you all know since it is a Managed Package ! Is there any way of getting all the custom object, field API names, record types and other stuffs in bulk and try creating in my other org ! Tried change sets but many objects are hidden and deployment connection is restricted from source org to destination org for some other reasons !! Pls suggest me if anyone has ever came across this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed packages apps are strictly locked .Meaning you cannot extract the package metadata and deploy them to other orgs without installing the managed package application.

The only way you could do is if you have access to the packaging org where the managed package application is build and you can use the source to move through metadata .Obviously only package vendor will have this and it's IP protected .Note that since the application is free and if developer has built as a part of community contribution he might be able to share with you the source .It's worth contacting the vendor . However that might not be the case as well if the vendor decides he wants to IP protect it .

The other option is to manually recreate the schema and other config that you can see .